# How to manage DbContext in a WPF Applicatoin

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I overtook a WPF project where entity framework is used. The person before me used a single global DbContext. After some reading it became clear that this is a bad practice because of several reasons. Now my job is to refactor the project to use a DbContextFactory and create new DbContext per unit-of-work.
One method i.e. `SaveSales` calls another method `IncreaseReceiptNumber`. Inside `IncreaseReceiptNumber` an entry is added to a table and SaveChanges is called. Now inside `SaveSales` i create a `DbContext` with `using (var clientDB = dbContextFactory.Create() {}`.
My question is, in a case like this should I pass the `DbContext` from `SaveSales` to `IncreaseReceiptNumber` or should `IncreaseReceiptNumber` create it's own `DbContext`? Or in a more general sense, should every method create a new `DbContext` or can a `DbContext` passed on via parameter if it belongs to the unit-of-work?

Comment: Can you give detail about SaveSales? What do the method? How is managed the transaction? A code example can help to understand your question.

Comment: Move the `DbContext` to a data access layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, there is no single answer to this question.  You must decide for each case whether or not the overhead of multiple connections is warranted (overhead is small with pooling, but exists), if the sharing of a single DbContext provides extra benefits (entities already attached), and if sharing makes things more difficult (you're calling the method in a loop, and risk "connection already open" errors) .  These factors have to be weighed on a case-by-case basis.  For what it's worth, I have done all of these things...use the right tool for the job, as they say.